# Reactor Theme: Prevent Post Thumb on Post

Tags: theme-development, post-thumbnails

Reactor Theme is built on Zurb Foundation and is [here](http://awtheme.com/) - I think it's quite good.

The theme I am replacing used the featured image in the posts or blog page but not in the post itself.  Reactor calls the image in both.  I want to try and change that so that I can have the featured image on the blog page and not in the post.  It causes a problem because I usually use the image in the post and use that for the blog page.

The Reactor theme uses lots of includes, functions, hooks and all that fancy shizzle so I am finding it complicated.  I think I have worked out that this is calling in the featured image:

```
function reactor_do_standard_thumbnail() { 
$link_titles = reactor_option('frontpage_link_titles', 0);

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<div class="entry-thumbnail">
    <?php if ( is_page_template('page-templates/front-page.php') && !$link_titles ) { 
        the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb-150' );
    } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb-150' ); ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php }
}
add_action('reactor_post_header', 'reactor_do_standard_thumbnail', 4);
```

The full code for that is [here](https://github.com/awtheme/reactor/blob/master/library/inc/content/content-posts.php) on Git.

Am I correct in thinking that this bit of code is what is doing what I think it is?  Can anyone give me a clue as to how I change this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: But are you using a Child Theme? If not, simply modify the function and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what cracked it:

```
function reactor_do_standard_thumbnail() { 
$link_titles = reactor_option('frontpage_link_titles', 0);  
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<div class="entry-thumbnail small-4 column">            
<?php if ( is_page_template('page-templates/front-page.php') && !$link_titles ) { 
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb-150' ); ?>
<?php } elseif ( is_single()){ ;?>
    <?php } else { ;?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"     title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb-150');     ?></a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php }
}
add_action('reactor_post_header', 'reactor_do_standard_thumbnail', 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Callback

This is how "Reactor" hooks the callback

```
add_action( 'reactor_post_header', 'reactor_do_standard_thumbnail', 4 );
```

#### Backtrace

The function itself is hooked from where you linked

```
~/theme_root/library/inc/content/content-post.php
```

**but** this file is called by the `class Reactor`. This class/file is **not** included during the main callback [hooked to `after_setup_theme` in the `functions.php` file on priority 10](https://github.com/awtheme/reactor/blob/master/library/reactor.php#L24), but before that without a callback. And it gets instantiated right afterwards:

```
require locate_template('library/reactor.php');
new Reactor();
```

When the class gets instantiated and the `__construct()`or gets called, it hooks the callback that registers the callback for the default thumb [on priority 14 on the `after_setup_theme` hook](https://github.com/awtheme/reactor/blob/master/library/reactor.php#L24) ... (FYI: in lame PHP 4 style).

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', array( &$this, 'content' ), 14);
```

Then [the `content()` method](https://github.com/awtheme/reactor/blob/master/library/reactor.php#L70) does nothing else than including another file:

```
require_once locate_template('/library/inc/content/content-pages.php');
```

And **this file** is the one that actually attaches the default thumbnail [here](https://github.com/awtheme/reactor/blob/master/library/inc/content/content-posts.php#L89).

```
add_action('reactor_post_header', 'reactor_do_standard_thumbnail', 4);
```

#### Exchange

Now simply add the following in [your ***CHILD THEME*** `functions.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) file.

```
/**
 * Remove the original callback, add in a new one
 */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse119843RemoveStandardThumbs', 20 );
function wpse119843RemoveStandardThumbs()
{
    // Removes it for posts AND pages. If you only want posts, use is_single()
    if ( is_singular() )
        remove_action( 'reactor_post_header', 'reactor_do_standard_thumbnail', 4 );

    add_action( 'reactor_post_header', 'wpse119843AddCustomThumbs' );
}
/**
 * The callback that formats the new output
 */
function wpse119843AddCustomThumbs()
{
    $link_titles = reactor_option( 'frontpage_link_titles', 0 );

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
    {
        ?>
        // REFACTOR REACTOR
        <?php
    }

}
```

### NOTE

To preserve your changes, use a ***Child Theme***. When you take a closer look at the site, then [you'll see that there already exists one](http://awtheme.com/portfolio-post/empty-core/).

Comment: OMG!  That is awesome help. I will have to wait to tomorrow to try it but you seem to have explained it brilliantly. I'll get back to you when I get it implemented. Thanks again.